# How to retrieve value from textbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I am trying to retrieve the value from the textbox (Email), however i do not know how to do so as i am new ASP.NET MVC5.

Currently i have this code that gets require the user to enter their email.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Email, New With {.class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Email, New With {.class = "form-control"})
    </div>
</div>
```

And below is the method that will create a pop up to get user's acknowledgement on the creation of an account.

```
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

//the code below is #myModel

```
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure you want to Register an account</p> // want to add the email that was input in the textbox earlier on**

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register"> Submit </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The controller for register is below

```
Public Function Register() As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function

<HttpPost>
<AllowAnonymous>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken>

Public Async Function Register(model As RegisterViewModel) As Task(Of ActionResult)
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        Dim user = New ApplicationUser() With {
            .UserName = model.Email,
            .Email = model.Email
        }
        Dim result = Await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)
        If result.Succeeded Then
            Await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:=False, rememberBrowser:=False)
            Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
        End If
        AddErrors(result)
    End If

    Return View(model)
End Function
```

Comment: Could you paste your controller code too?

Comment: What is your actual problem? It seems you have everything you need here. Is the email being posted as null? Are you trying to retrieve it via JavaScript? What is the exact issue?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the value from the textbook m.email and use that value in my pop up box. However i do not know how to do that .

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Email, New With {.class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
   <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Email,, new { id = "EmailID", @clas= "orm-control", placeholder = "EmailID" })
   </div>
</div>
```

And on javascript U can get the value like this

```
 var meetingRoom = $('#meetingRoom').val();
```

Comment: Hi. I do understand that we can use the $('#testing').val(); however  what i am trying is to is to retrieve the value from the input box
<div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Email, New With {.class = "form-control"})
    </div>

Are you trying to say i should put like id="email" in the row of <div class="col-md-10"> such that it will appear like this <div class="col-md-10", id="email">?